# any one help me to solve this thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ios4

I am getting an error

> thread 1: signal SIGABRT

This is the code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    /* FOR SIMPLE CELL */
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];


    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    word *worddc = [Array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; //ERROR thread 1 signal SIGABRT

        cell.textLabel.text = worddc.word_alphabet;



    return cell;
}
```

Comment: We need more infos to help. Why is this code useful ? What are you trying to do with it ? *Thread 1: signal SIGABRT* is very very very general and does not help at all if you don't give more infos.

Comment: You should uppercase classes ("Word") and lowercase variables ("array").

Comment: I guess it has to be memory management problem . Are you sure that Array is a valid reference ? It might have been deallocated .

Comment: @Engineer just check your array name it seems that you are populating the data from the `Array` dataType itself.check you instance name.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following list:

- Check if Array is still allocated and it's not been deallocate.
- Try cast the value like this:

  ```
  word *worddc = (word *)[Array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
  ```

Comment: @EngineerUet Check whether your array is being allocated anywhere ? Mostly it should be allocated in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

I commented saying you need to explain your problem, but I may have an idea anyways :

`objectAtIndex:` returns an *(id)* object. Try to cast the result to word* :

```
word *worddc = (word*)[Array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way and check what you are getting in the strObj, is it string?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    /* FOR SIMPLE CELL */
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) 
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    word *worddc = [Array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; //ERROR thread 1 signal SIGABRT
    NSString *strObj=worddc.word_alphabet;
    cell.textLabel.text =strObj;//Here check what you are getting by setting breakpoint.
    strObj=nil;



    return cell;
}
```